# Reset git credentials (Github)

Tags: git, github, credentials

I have two Github accounts: private and for work. Each associated with different credentials. Let's name these credentials `PRIVATE` and `WORK`.

Currently, my system seems to be using the work-related credentials `WORK`. When I tried to delete/change these credentials and push to my private repo, I still get:

```
git push --set-upstream origin main
ERROR: Permission to my_private_repo denied to WORK.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I'm using Mac, deleted all git-related items from Keychain.
When I do

```
git credential-osxkeychain erase
host=github.com 
protocol=https
```

the terminal hangs.

Can you please tell me how to completely remove the `WORK` credentials from the computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do check your remote URL is indeed an HTTPS one (if it is SSH, no amount of keychain fiddling would matter, since the ketchain is used to cached HTTPS credentials).

```
cd /path/to/repository
git remote -v
```

Second, for an HTTPS URL, deleting the credentials would be:

```
printf "host=github.com\nprotocol=https\nusername=YourWorkLogin" | git credential-osxkeychain erase
```

Comment: thank you very much, it was ssh instead of https!